# Cannot schema bind view 'v_rolling_12_sales' because name 'DataTrue_Report.dbo.InvoiceDetails' is invalid for schema binding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Trying to create a view with a cluster index, keep running into a brick wall with creating the view with schemabinding. I am using all 2 part identifiers in my query and I've followed all the rules on Microsoft's site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

For some reason it just doesn't want to enable schema binding (I was able to create the view without schemabinding, but I'm looking to have an indexed view for performance purposes)

```
    alter view dbo.v_rolling_12_sales with SCHEMABINDING

as

select c.ChainName, c.ChainID, s.SupplierName, s.SupplierIdentifier, s.SupplierID,

sum(isnull(i.TotalCost,0)) as costDollars, sum(isnull(i.TotalRetail,0)) as retailDollars, COUNT_BIG(*) as countBig

from DataTrue_Report.dbo.InvoiceDetails as i with (nolock)

inner join DataTrue_Report.dbo.Suppliers as s
on s.SupplierID = i.SupplierID

inner join DataTrue_Report.dbo.Chains as c
on c.ChainID = i.ChainID

where s.IsRegulated = 0 and i.SaleDate > '2/13/17' and i.InvoiceDetailTypeID in (1,7) and i.TotalQty > 0

group by c.ChainName, s.SupplierName, s.SupplierIdentifier, c.ChainName, c.ChainID, s.SupplierName, s.SupplierIdentifier, s.SupplierID
GO


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ChainSupplier ON v_rolling_12_sales (SupplierID, ChainID, ChainName, SupplierIdentifier, SupplierName)
GO
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You can't schema bind (nor create an index on) a view that references an object in a different database. There is no trick or hack to make this work. If you want an indexed view, you have to create the view in the `DataTrue_Report` database. If you want to reference *that* view without the database prefix, then create a view that selects from it, or create a synonym.

Comment: All of this is in the `DataTrue_Report` database, I tried creating the view with the full `DataTrue_Report.dbo.v_rolling_12_sales` name but got the error message 'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: Remove the "DataTrue_Report" qualifier on your INNER JOINs.

Comment: @pmbAustin - didn't work. Intellisense also suggested I keep the joins and the from statements fully qualified

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and stop using NOLOCK, especially in a view. You can end up doing all sort of really nasty things. Aaron has a great discussion on the hidden "benefits" this hint brings. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And in a view it is really bad because the consumer of that view may not realize the data is potentially wrong. And date literals should be ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD. Those literals you have are ambiguous and can cause errors with different language settings.

Comment: If it's all in the same database, there is no purpose or benefit to fully qualifying like that, and it's illegal to specify a database name when you intend to schemabind, so... stop that.

Comment: Make sure your SSMS window is in the context of the right database. The. You don’t need the database name on the view or the joins inside the view.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, I hate using nolock, but got a nice long speech from my companies DBA about how we should use NOLOCK at all times...

Comment: You should give a nice long speech explaining that he clearly doesn't know what he is talking about. I worked as a consultant for a company who made that decision. We processed debit card payments. I warned their "uber smart" know it all DBA about the pitfalls and was told that is how they were going to do it. We had all sorts of issues of declining payments when money was available and allowing payments when there was no money. They spent 6 months adding in that hint, ran with it for about 9, then another 6 months to take it back out. Ended up costing them millions of dollars.

Comment: And of course....you didn't use NOLOCK everywhere, it is only on one table. :)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions in a materialized view should not reference a  null-able column. Try aggregate functions with non-nullable column. And also include count_big(*) along with your aggregate funtion.

Regards,
Ananda Kumar J.

Comment: count_big(*) was included in the query and I wrapped isnulls around all the aggregation columns just to play it safe...

Comment: Your clustered index key columns and the columns used in group by clause is different. Try to address this, this may solve the issue.